# call function from ID

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, append

I've been trying to add content with function. When I click anchor should be adding content with same anchor ID, I'm thinking this logic is right, but nothing is happen. Is there any better way to get this right.

```js
$('.tab a').click(function(){
  var tabAnchor = $(this).attr('href');
  
  if($(tabAnchor)=='#info'){
    callInfo();
  }
  else if($(tabAnchor)=='#category'){
    callCategory();
  }
  
})


function callInfo(){
  $('#info').append('<p>Info has been added</p>')
}

function callCategory(){
  $('#info').append('<p>Category has been added</p>')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="tab">
  <li><a href=#info>info</a></li>
  <li><a href=#category>category</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="info">

</div>

<div id="category">

</div>
```

Comment: use html() instead of append

Comment: `if ($(tabAnchor)=='#info')` ? You're comparing a jQuery object with a string...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is your `if` statement where you compare a jQuery object to a string - this will never return true. Instead, you should compare the strings directly, like this:

```js
$('.tab a').click(function() {
  var tabAnchor = $(this).attr('href');
  if (tabAnchor == '#info') {
    callInfo();
  } else if (tabAnchor == '#category') {
    callCategory();
  }
})

function callInfo() {
  $('#info').append('<p>Info has been added</p>')
}

function callCategory() {
  $('#info').append('<p>Category has been added</p>')
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="tab">
  <li><a href="#info">info</a></li>
  <li><a href="#category">category</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="info"></div>
<div id="category"></div>
```

Also note that you can make the logic much simpler and easier to maintain by having a single function that performs the logic based on the clicked `href`:

```js
$('.tab a').click(function() {
  var tabAnchor = $(this).attr('href');
  $(tabAnchor).append('<p>' + tabAnchor.substring(1) + ' has been added</p>')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="tab">
  <li><a href="#info">info</a></li>
  <li><a href="#category">category</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="info"></div>
<div id="category"></div>
```

Comment: I see, I thought when I create variable is still require $ sign to comparing with string.

Comment: No not at all. In JS the `$` prefix has no intrinsic meaning at all. It's just a naming convention that denotes a variable that holds a jQuery object